# Is consent screen is compulsory for any openid connect / Oauth2? Why?

Tags: oauth

Why the consent screen is compulsory, Is this specific rule for openId connect?

Can you please suggest me.

Answer (score 0):

> Why the consent screen is compulsory

It is not. As shown in the [oauth-parameters registry](https://www.iana.org/assignments/oauth-parameters/oauth-parameters.xhtml#parameters), the "[prompt](http://ldapwiki.com/wiki/Prompt%20Parameter)" is an optional parameter.

> Is this specific rule for openId connect?

Yes. OpenID connect builds upon OAuth 2.0 and the "[prompt](http://ldapwiki.com/wiki/Prompt%20Parameter)" parameter was added for OpenID Conenct.

> Can you please suggest me.

For the sake of integrity, the prompt should **NOT** be bypassed unless there is some prior **consent** agreement between the parties.

Comment: Example of (implicit) prior consent: an app asking an access token to an API, by using its refresh token. _It is clear_ that the app does authorise the auth server to fetch details on behalf of them, before assessing if issuing an access token is all right, or not...